# Can I have tooltips as well as a legend for one set of datapoints?

Tags: javascript, flot

The example linked [here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html) shows that tooltips relies on the manipulation of the `label` attribute, which I am currently using as the legend. How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: Do you want the tooltip to show a string other than the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip doesn't rely on the label. You can use the label in the tooltip, but you don't have to.

Just follow the examples and if you have a specific problem, come back here (and create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if possible).